# Azure Devops configuration with Jenkins

Tags: azure-devops, azure-virtual-network

Background info:

Both Jenkins and Azure DevOps are located in Azure. Jenkins is not accessible from internet and is behind organization firewall where as Azure DevOps is not, need an ability to use Jenkins Service hook with mentioned background

Also can below be possible :

1. possibility to configure Azure DevOps in local Azure VNET
2. If we can identify or get Azure DevOps host server IP to white-list it for incoming traffic in Jenkins.

Comment: The way to go is to configure Express Route: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/expressroute-for-azure-devops/

Answer (score 0):

The way to link Azure DevOps to your private Azure VNETs, is through Express Route.

> Connectivity to Microsoft online services like Azure Storage, Azure SQL, Dynamics 365 and now Azure DevOps is through the Microsoft peering configuration of ExpressRoute circuits.
>
> Route filters are a way to consume a subset of supported services through Microsoft peering. Using route filters, you can enable services you want to consume through your circuit’s Microsoft peering. Azure DevOps is included in the new Azure Global Services route filter with a BGP community value of `12076:5050`.
>
> ExpressRoute is available for all Azure DevOps services, including:
>
> - Organizations using the new `https://dev.azure.com/` URL,
> - Organizations using the legacy `https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/` URL,
> - Self-hosted Azure Pipelines agents,
> - Self-hosted Cloud Load Test agents,
> - Visual Studio Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/),
> - Visual Studio Subscriber Portal (https://my.visualstudio.com), and
> - Visual Studio Subscriptions Administration Portal (https://manage.visualstudio.com).
>
> ExpressRoute is not available for Azure DevOps static content that is delivered via Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN), which includes:
>
> - Scripts, images, fonts and stylesheets, from the cdn.vsassets.io URL, and
> - Web extensions from the {publishername}.gallerycdn.vsassets.io URL.
>
> ExpressRoute is available for use with Azure Artifacts. However, you will need to configure route filters for the Microsoft Azure region that your organization is located in.

See also:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/expressroute-for-azure-devops/https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/expressroute-for-azure-devops/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/expressroute/how-to-routefilter-portal

Comment: Could you please add more on how & where we can find express route details in Azure Devops? or else?

Comment: Express route details are all inside of Azure. It's through VNet linking and pairing that this trick is accomplished. The docs are all here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/